# What is the best way to export library method, when using Closure Compiler?

Tags: javascript, google-closure-compiler

Closure Compiler documentation clearly states: "Don't use Externs instead of Exports". Because Externs are very handy to use, I came down with a problem:

```
function Lib(){ 
  //some initialization  
}
Lib.prototype = {
  invoke : function(str){
     //this function is called from outside to invoke some of Lib's events
  }  
}
```

When using Closure Compiler with **ADVANCED_OPTIMIZATIONS**, function invoke is removed from the source. This could be prevented in two ways:
Adding the line after prototype definition:

```
Lib.prototype['invoke'] = Lib.prototype.invoke;
```

But this adds an ugly peace of code at the end of the output code:

```
Lib.prototype.invoke = Lib.prototype.g;
```

I managed to get rid of this by adding this line to the constructor:

```
this.invoke = this.invoke;
```

And this line to the externs file:

```
/**
* @param {String} str
*/ 
Lib.prototype.invoke = function(str){};
```

This way, Closure Compiler can't remove invoke function from the output code, because it is assigned by itself in the constructor, and also, it can't rename it, because it is defined in the externs file.
So witch method is better?

Answer (score 3):

If you use JSDoc consistently, you could use the [`@export` tag](http://google-styleguide.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/javascriptguide.xml?showone=Comments#Comments):

```
/**
* @param {String} str
* @export
*/ 
Lib.prototype.invoke = function(str){
     //this function is called from outside to invoke some of Lib's events
};
```

and call the compiler with the `--generate_exports` flag.

This requires you to either include [`base.js`](http://closure-library.googlecode.com/svn/docs/closure_goog_base.js.html) from the Google Closure library, or to copy `goog.exportSymbol` and `goog.exportProperty` to your codebase.

Comment: This could be done without the `@export` tag: `Lib.prototype['invoke'] = function(str){};`

Comment: Using the `export` tag will still rename the method though and the short name is used internally. It just seems to be a cleaner approach to use the full potential of the compiler and is more descriptive.

Comment: Agree, but your suggested method with the `export` tag involves `goog` namespace, because of this the library can't be used as stand-alone.

Comment: As I said, you can just add those two methods to your codebase (copy & paste). That's also described in the style guide. Apart from that, the *compiled* library can always be used stand alone as all dependencies are added to *one* file.

Answer (score 3):

Personally, I like defining interfaces in externs file and having my internal classes implement them.

```
// Externs

/** @interface */
function IInvoke {};
IInvoke.prototype.invoke;

/** 
 *  @constructor
 *  @implements {IInvoke}
 */
function Lib(){ 
  //some initialization  
}
Lib.prototype = {
  invoke : function(str){
     //this function is called from outside to invoke some of Lib's events
  }  
}
```

You still export the constructor itself, but not the interface methods.