# Obfuscate Javascript that's object oriented

Tags: javascript, oop, dom-events

There are tons of Javascript obfuscation websites out there that do the trick, but I'm not sure what to do when the code is created with OOP.

As an aside, I'm obfuscating to reduce size and readability. I know full well it doesn't seriously protect anything at all.

For example:

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function() {  
    myFunction.init(); // init

    });

</script>
```

file.js

```
var myFunction = function () {

    return {

        //main function to initiate the module
        init: function () {
          alert('whole bunch of other stuff in here');
        }
    }
}
```

If I obfuscate file.js, the `myFunction.init()` term is lost to the program, as it's been renamed to a variable of some kind.

Also, an addition problem is that if a function within the init is called from a different class or function, it's still lost because of the variable name change.

Any ideas? Best practices?

Comment: Why don't you just minify it? JS files are never "secure"

Comment: What obfuscator are you using? I feel like a good one wouldn't do that. Or, you may have to flag it for the obfuscator to not touch it

Comment: your example doesn't work. I'm using requirejs in my larger projects. It have a command based uglify rotine `r.js -o shim_file.json` http://requirejs.org

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you are trying to do is commonly known `export`ing. Some obfuscators will include a doc-block tag you can add to protect names like this.

Perhaps, this question will help: [What is the best way to export library method, when using Closure Compiler?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9111900/what-is-the-best-way-to-export-library-method-when-using-closure-compiler)

Otherwise, you will need to look at the optimizer you are using to see if they support a similar feature.  If not, you'll want to look for a different optimizer.

Answer (score 0):

I have just written my own object-oriented Javascript code obfuscator, and my conclusion is that it is very difficult to write a general purpose one for anybody to use, which may explain the lack of publicly available tools.  In order for mine to work, I have to be sure that the code at my business adheres to consistent coding practices.  If you are serious about code obfuscation and aren't willing to write a "compiler-quality" obfuscator (I wrote mine in Perl and never used lex), here's my advice:

1. Obfuscate your code incrementally so that after each step, the code still works.  The idea here is that there are lots of things that could be renamed, and if you rename them all at once, it'll be hard to troubleshoot if your obfuscation breaks the code.  In my case, the first step was to identify object names and member function names without doing any obfuscation.  I used a configuration file that contained the list of all files I wanted obfuscated, and I also made it possible to specify specific object names and member function names that explicitly should not be obfuscated.  For example, if you named a function push(), you might not want to obfuscate that function name because your obfuscator runs the risk of messing up an array's call to push().  As another example, if your client code instantiates a particular object by name, then you should choose not to obfuscate that object's name.  The output of step1 was a list of all identified object names, function names, and the proposed obfuscated name for each.
2. In my version, step 2 then reads in all of the files defined in one configuration file, uses the obfuscation mapping, and outputs a single Javascript file.  Since we had 3 separate projects that are related, we actually had 3 configuration files and 3 output files.  The original source code is composed of dozens of files, so this is quite a difference for us.
3. The next phase in our obfuscation project is to rename member variables using a process similar to steps 1 and 2.
4. The final phase is to run a legitimate minify program, such as closure-compiler.jar.  This will have the effect of obfuscating all of your local variables and removing unneeded whitespace.

The final result is a nearly incomprehensible file.  We use a script that batches it all up together, so obfuscation is automated and painless.  We also have an alternative script that packages the files just the same, but without obfuscation in case we need to troubleshoot a problem.

Here's some additional advice:
1. Make sure every object you declare begins with a capital letter and every global function you declare does not begin with a capital letter.  This will make it possible to differentiate  between objects and normal functions.
2. Name every member variable using a consistent prefix.  In my case, I begin all member variables with the letter "m" followed by a capital letter.  For example, instead of this.name, use this.mName.  If you are consistent with this practice, you can safely rename uses of member variables with a pretty trivial script.

I'm sorry that we are not open-sourcing our object-oriented Javascript obfuscator.  We don't have the time available to offer any support for it, so we're not releasing it publicly, but I have given you the essence of what we've done from an organizational standpoint, so I hope it helps.

Comment: This sounds like a lot of work and very tedious. You really wanna go through that process everytime you make a small change to your code? Obfuscating should be an automated process.

Comment: It is an automated process. We use configuration files and can completely obfuscate everything in one script, which runs a series of steps. We have dozens of Javascript objects in dozens of files, but we're able to obfuscate cohesive groups of code into single files